# How accurate is python's time.sleep() for long time periods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I'm wondering how accurate python's time.sleep() method is for longer time periods spanning from a few minutes up to a few days.

My concern is, that there might be a drift which will add up when using this method for longer time periods.

Alternatively I have come up with a different solution to end a loop after a certain amount of time has passed:

```py
end = time.time() + 10000

while 1:
    if time.time() > end:
        break
```

This is accurate down to a few milliseconds which is fine for my use case and won't drift over time.

Comment: did you check the temperature of your CPU when doing this?

Comment: This is simply an excerpt to demonstrate my idea. No need to make it more complicated to read by adding unnecessary statements

Comment: calculating the exact amout of time needed to sleep() and sleeping that will be also accurate to within a few milliseconds (systeminterrrupts and scheduled events might prevent 100% accuracy) - if you do that every time you sleep() you will not drift a lot - and your electricity bill, your CPU and your neighbours (Fans are loud) will thank you for it. Your code is the equivalent of looking at your wristwatch every half a second for 7 hours versus setting the alarm clock to now plus 7h and sleeping until the alarm goes off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `time.sleep()` function is accurate and should be used in this case as it is simpler and easier to run. An example is

```py
time.sleep(10000) # will stop all running scripts in the same pid
```

Using a bare while statement without any threshold will use a lot of your resources, which is why you should use a time.sleep expression to reduce this. You also should have used the while statement condition statement as this will make sure your while statement closes.

As shown below

```py
end = time.time() + 10000

while end > time.time(): # ensures to end when time.time (now) is more than end
    time.sleep(0.001) # creates a 1 ms gap to decrease cpu usage
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the pause module, you can get millisecond precision over a period of days. No need to roll your own here.

https://github.com/jgillick/python-pause

Answer (score 1):

Python's time.sleep() is accurate for any length of time with two little flaws:

1. The time `t` must be considered "at least `t` seconds" as there may be a
   number of system events that are scheduled to start at the precise moment
   "time when started" + `t`.
2. The sleep may be interrupted if the signal handler raises an exception.

I think, but am not certain, that these flaws are found in most programming languages.